# Uncaught Reference: App is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

this code is supposed to help do an animation with my website and I don't know what is preventing it. In the debugger console, all i am receiving is a Uncaught reference: app is not defined.

```
app.skills = {
    init: function () {
        $(".skills h1").blast({
            delimiter: "character",
            tag: "span"
        });
        $(".skills p").blast({
            delimiter: "word",
            tag: "span"
        });
        a = 0;
        $(".skills h1 .blast").each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.addClass('animated bounceIn');
            }, a);
            a = a + 80;
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".skills .blast").removeClass('animated bounceIn');
            $(".skills .blast").css('opacity', 1);
            $(".skills .blast").mouseenter(function () {
                var el = $(this);
                $(this).addClass('animated rubberBand');
                $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                    el.removeClass('animated rubberBand');
                });
            });
        }, 2000);
        a = 0;
        $('.chart').not('.small').each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.addClass('animated rotateIn');
                el.circliful();
            }, a)
            a = a + 200;
        });
        a = 0;
        $('.chart.small').each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.addClass('animated flipInX');
                el.circliful();
            }, a)
            a = a + 100;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using? Where is app defined?

Comment: Can you explain us what is app ? Do you use frameworks ?

Comment: Test once with declaring `app = app || {};` before `app.skills =`

Comment: App is not defined. You need to define app. If this is not a framework you could simply define it by doing something like `var app = {};`

Comment: Read the error message. It means `app` is not defined. Clearly in your code `app` is never defined and you are trying to access its property.